# Recognizing a column as a date in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a column of characters in a data.frame which I want to be recognized as dates:

For example I tried:

```
 dat <- c("2013.05.30","2013.05.29","2013.05.28","2013.05.27")

 dat1 <- gsub(".", "-", dat)
```

But this returns:

"----------" "----------" "----------" "----------"
while I want

"2013-05-30","2013-05-29","2013-05-28","2013-05-27"

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to simply coerce them to dates?

```
as.Date(dat,format = "%Y.%m.%d")
```

The reason your `gsub` doesn't work is because `.` has a special meaning in regex. You can have it interpreted literally by specifying `fixed = TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

in your gsub call, "." is your pattern. The "." symbol in a pattern means "any character", so you're talling gsub to replace every character with a dash. The correct `gsub` call requires escaping the period so R knows this is a literal period:

```
d1 <- gsub("\\.", "-", dat)
```

This syntax will have gsub replace all periods with dashes. But really, this isn't what you want, you want *dates*. You need to use `as.Date` like so:

```
d2 <- as.Date(dat, format="%Y.%m.%d")
```

Your intended solution would only have converted your strings to a different string format. Using as.Date tells R to treat the values as dates and not strings.

```
plot(d1)
```

will produce an error (because R doesn't understand what you want when you ask it to plot nothing but strings), whereas:

```
plot(d2)
```

Produces a plot of index vs. day of the week (since R recognizes that you have timeseries data).